# Shell scripts: undefined -a, -o switch behavior

Tags: posix, sh, undefined-behavior, logical-operators

According to the [shellcheck wiki](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2166):

> `-a` and `-o` to mean `AND` and `OR` in a [ .. ] test expression is not well defined. They are obsolescent extensions in POSIX and their behavior is almost always undefined.

Any idea what wrong can happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_16 for a discussion about the problems `-a` and `-o` can raise. In general, how the expression is parsed becomes dependent on what any parameters expand to. Consider the following test:

```
test "$1" -a "$2"
```

Depending on the value of `$1`, this could be either

```
# Unspecified behavior
# With three arguments, the first "!", the second argument
# must be a unary primary like -n or -f.
test "!" -a "$2"
```

or

```
test "foo" -a "$2"  # Test that "foo" and "$2" are non-zero length strings
```

If `$1` is `!`, `test` will treat that as the negation operator, not a string to whose length should be checked.

Also, `test` is only well-defined for 4 or fewer arguments; `-a` and `-o` usually result in 5 or more arguments being passed to `test`.